# Python nested loop doesn't loop

Tags: python, csv, nested-loops

I'm a python beginner and I can't make my loop loop.

Here's the case : I've got two csv files (event logs).

First on is called bd8result.csv with 4 or 5 lines structured like these :

```
2015/10/30 09:53:44,blabla1,259373865,95,F,A1 IP Thers,A1SIP V1 (R),-,,1446195224
2015/10/30 11:03:14,blabla2,259431070,32,F,A7 IP MornOs,A7SIP V1 (R),-,,1446199394
2015/10/30 21:30:59,blabla3,259980991,86,F,A2 IP Hor4ain,A2IP V1 (R),-,,1446237059
```

First column is the date, second is the IP event (*target*), last on is the epoch time.

I need to find blabla1, blabla2 and blabla3 and events associated 20mn before and 20 minute after these events, in a bigger log file that has the same structure and write the result in a csv file.
I just collect events located on the same *lecteur* info (so comes the test in *if...*).

My code looks like this :

```
with open('result_'+ namefile + '.csv', 'rb') as master1, open('epoch_'+ namefile + '.csv', 'rb') as hosts1:
    reader2 = csv.reader(master1)
    reader1 = csv.reader(hosts1)
    for row in reader2:
        target = row[1]
        lecteur = row[5]
        epoch_ref = int(row[-1])
        for row2 in reader1:
            epoch1 = int(row2[-1])
            lecteur1 = row2[5]
            with open('result_scout' + namefile + '.csv', 'a') as results1:
                 if epoch1 > (epoch_ref - ecart) and epoch1 < (epoch_ref + ecart) and lecteur1 == lecteur:
                    writer1 = csv.writer(results1)
                    writer1.writerow([target]+[sys.argv[1]]+row2)
                    results1.close()
```

My problem is that it executes correctly the first item (*blabla1*), but doesn' write anything for blabla2 and blabla3.

I've tried several thing but I'm stucked.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Protip: To format text as code (keeping indentations etc.), paste it into the edit box, select the entire block and press Ctrl-K to indent all the lines by four spaces. No need to mess around with backticks or `<code>` tags; those are meant only for short inline code snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After one iteration of looping over `reader2`, `reader1` is exhausted  by its for loop and raises `StopIteration` and won't return anything in the successive loops.

You should get a new instance of `csv.reader` in every iteration:

```
with open('result_'+ namefile + '.csv', 'rb') as master1:
    for row in csv.reader(master1):
        target = row[1]
        lecteur = row[5]
        epoch_ref = int(row[-1])
        with open('epoch_'+ namefile + '.csv', 'rb') as hosts1:
            for row2 in csv.reader(hosts1):
                epoch1 = int(row2[-1])
                lecteur1 = row2[5]
                with open('result_scout' + namefile + '.csv', 'a') as results1:
                     if epoch1 > (epoch_ref - ecart) and epoch1 < (epoch_ref + ecart) and lecteur1 == lecteur:
                        writer1 = csv.writer(results1)
                        writer1.writerow([target]+[sys.argv[1]]+row2)
                        results1.close()
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> **csv.reader(csvfile)**
>
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given
>   csvfile. csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator
>   protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called.

This implies that after the reader raises `StopIteration` it will be exhausted just like an exhausted generator.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian!!
It definitely works like a charm this way!!