# dict () - Python 2.7 From 3.5 -

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, python-3.5

Following my work on my [prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734371/python-nested-loop-doesnt-loop), I'm still trying to compare two CSV files.
This time I use a dictionary.

My first file is something like:

```
IP
192.168.10.1
192.168.10.15
192.168.10.32
```

One single column, with IP addresses.

I want to check if these IP are also I another file called epoch.csv.
If yes, I write a CSV file with the copy of the line in epoch.csv.

In Python 2.7, I wrote this code that works smoothly:

```
with open('IP.csv', 'r') as master:
    enum = csv.reader(master)
    master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(enum))


with open('epoch.csv', 'r') as hosts:
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as results:
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        for row in reader:
            index = master_indices.get(row[1])
            if index is not None:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

BUT, when I try to run this code with Python 3.5 (Windows), I get this error:

```
File "IP.py", line 43, in (module)
master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(enum))
File "IP.py", line 43, in (genexpr)
master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(enum))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does it work in one case and not in the other one. I could of course reinstall 2.7 On all my machines, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work...

**EDIT :**

So considering csv.DictReader, I guess I can modify this line :

```
with open('IP.csv', 'r') as master:
    enum = csv.reader(master)
    master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(enum))
```

with something much simplier like this :

```
with open('IP.csv', 'r') as master:
    enum = csv.Dict.Reader(master)
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Python provide a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: Ok, so I check and edit my code

Comment: This looks like a symptom of `csv` finding an empty line at the end of the input file. Not sure why it would only affect 3.5, but I'd make sure the file doesn't end in a blank line, and/or filter the output, changing the initialization of `master_indices` to `master_indices = {r[0]: i for i, r in enumerate(enum) if r}` to exclude blank lines.

Comment: Break the expression down into into a regular loop iteration (not comprehension) and try printing `r` before you execute `r[0]`. I presume that's the culprit. I don't see such an issue myself, its probably something to do with your input file content.

Comment: @Cyrbil: It's kind of pointless to use the `DictReader` when you only have one field, and the value associated with it is the line number (which `DictReader` won't populate for you).

Comment: Oh, one other note: Files opened for `csv` processing in Py3.5 should be opened with keyword arg `newline=''`. Probably won't matter for your input, but it's the only way to do spec correct `csv` parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any empty lines in `IP.csv`?

Your code DID run "smoothly" in my computer under Python 3.5, but it will fail if I add a empty line to the start of the file.

Try to add `print(enum)` in your for loop and you will know what exactly lead to this exception.